# Configure token extraction проблема с нахождением data.token для NbPasswordAuthStrategy на nebular (angular 9)

Tags: веб-программирование, angularjs, angular

спасибо что перешли на мой вопрос! Никак не могу понять где найти этот data.token для NbPasswordAuthStrategy!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]